# What would discovery of a magnetic monopole do for a civilization?

Tags: internal-consistency, physics

Is discovering a magnetic monopole really something that would benefit humanity or is it just a physicists wet dream. If said monopole existed, what could it's discovery do for a civilization. Basically does it have any useful applications?

Comment: Nobody knows what discovering anything can do before it is done.

Comment: Questions asking "How would x affect civilization?" are too broad for this site.

Comment: Is it just one monopole, or have we discovered how to produce large amounts of them? The results in each case would be quite different.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Magnetic monopoles are used to create structural materials stronger than any "normal" matter (by many orders of magnitude) in the hard science space opera Orion's Arm:
http://www.orionsarm.com/eg-article/48630634d2591

Answer (score 0):

There is possibility that monopoles would work as catalyst for thermonuclear reactions. It is used in Niven's Known Space series.